# Принцип и этапы создания messenger для android

Tags: android, retrofit, rest, messenger

У меня есть приложение на Андроид, которое должно работать по принципу месенджера, то есть что-бы там были все функции стандартного месенджера.

Я уже частично ознакомился с вопросом создания чата, например при помощи firebase. Но у меня уже есть список всех пользователей которые будут в базе этого месенджера, мне нужно как-то сделать возможно поиска людей в БД, и потом при нахождении нужного нам человека мы должны сначала отправить ему запрос на добавление в друзья, или что-то типа такого, и потом после добавления, мы можем ему писать, данное приложение делается как полноценная адаптация сайте на мобильных устройствах, так-же нужно сделать много мелких вещей которые присутствуют в каждом стандартном месенджере.

Я так думаю что мне нужно будет работать с запросами post и get. Но я не могу понять с чего начинать, на сервере уже делают апи для работы моего приложения, но пока-что мне нужно понять с чего начинать, и разработать общую стратегию развития приложения. Если кто-то уже занимался разработкой подобного приложения, или может что-то посоветовать то буду очень благодарен за советы и за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря ваш вопрос слишком общий. Если у вас есть серверная сторона, то большинство проблем должно решаться на стороне сервера: хранение пользователей, поиск человека, отправка запроса на авторизацию, передача сообщения от клиента к клиенту и т.п. В таком случае, приложение выступает только в качестве клиента. Оно общается только с сервером, а сервер организует взаимодействие клиентов, переправляя сообщения туда и обратно. На стороне клиента вы реализуете все "рюшечки и красоту", а так же шифрование (т.к. отправлять сообщение в открытом виде - плохая практика).

Итоге: при наличие сервера, приложение всего лишь клиент, полностью завязанный на апи. Если бы вы делали чат с firebase без сервера, то клиент был-бы толстым и выполнял бы одновременно функции сервера.

Comment: то есть мне нужно только изучить принципы отправки запросов на сервер, а что и куда там будет переправляться то это не мои проблемы?

Comment: Узнайте, что за апи у сервера. Узнайте о назначении сервера. Без плотной работы с бекендщиками, вы просто не сможете реализовать именно то, что им нужно. Какие запросы умеет обрабатывать сервер, как он на них отвечает и что отправляет?. Человек, который делает серверную сторону, может реализовать что угодно. Полагаю, что наиболее правильный вариант будет тот, который я ва описал, но может может отличаться. Итого: трясите бекендщиков. На основе их сервера, планируете свое приложение (аля: запрос за список чатов. При клике на чат - запрос за сообщениями) Много тонкостей, без конкретики никак.

Comment: я понял, спасибо за совет, буду трясти бекендщиков, авось чего выведаю, но вообще серверное апи это rest api, для логина я использовал retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать взять готовую платформу, с готовыми кусками кода и просто изменить ее под себя. многие провайдеры предлагают бесплатные версии, вот здесь, например:
https://developers.connectycube.com/android/